# Software that display the browser functionalities

Tags: browser

Is there a software or script that can detect the internet browser functionalities? (e.g. Support CSS3, HTML5, etc)

Comment: Please explain in more detail what you want to accomplish.

Comment: I am looking something like Acid3 but can be download as a software and covers more standards beside XHTML, DOM, etc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) does just this.

> Modernizr is an open-source JavaScript library that helps you build the next generation of HTML5 and CSS3-powered websites.
>
> aking advantage of the new capabilities of HTML5 and CSS3 can mean sacrificing control over the experience in older browsers. Modernizr 2 is your starting point for making the best websites and applications that work exactly right no matter what browser or device your visitors use.
>
> Thanks to the new Media Query tests and built-in YepNope.js micro-library as Modernizr.load(), you can now combine feature detection with media queries and conditional resource loading. That gives you the power and flexibility to optimize for every circumstance.
>
> Check out the full list of features that Modernizr detects, or learn more about conditional resource loading with Modernizr.

Comment: I am looking for a 'more" complete browser functionalities detection. (It should at least covers 95% of existing standards)

Comment: What "standards" do you need to cover?

Comment: I can't imagine a more comprehensive suite for "existing standards" than Modernizr

Comment: @LarryMorries There are probably far more applicable standards than you can possibly imagine. Something like "at least 95% of existing standards" is unrealistic.

Answer (score -1):

No, since most of it is only visible to the end user (Do you really want an executable to pop up a few hundred yes/no dialog boxes? "Can you see it now? [Yes] [No]"). What can be done is a best guess based on the user agent of or JavaScript objects in the browser and the known properties of each.

Comment: This is absolutely the wrong way to solve this problem and a bad and largely incorrect.

Comment: It's interesting how this answer gets downvotes while a JavaScript script that does just this gets upvotes.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: It's the herd mentality. . .

Comment: @surfasb: Or experience dealing with feature detection, and what works and what doesn't. Sometimes "the herd" is right.

Answer (score -1):

CSS3 and HTML5 are a set of features that browsers will support fully, in part, or not at all.

So what you really need to do is determine whether the specific features you need are present.

You can do this for many features using the [jquery.support](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.support/) module.